Sign in with Google button migration to FedCM
Having the Sign in with Google button with redirects should I care about the migrations to FedCM? In the official docs I see:

This update is for all Google Identity Services (GIS) web developers who rely on the Chrome browser and use:
One Tap, or
Auto Sign-In
So nothing about the Sign in with Google button.

My HTML snippet is:

<div
    id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="foobar"
    data-context="signin"
    data-ux_mode="redirect"
    data-login_uri="http://myapp.com/foobar"
    data-auto_prompt="false"

As I understand in my case with redirects third party cookies are not used so my solution will be still supported without any migration?

Both UX flow (popup and redirect) would be affected. Set the data-use_fedcm_for_prompt to true to make sure your sign in flow works.
